# Problem moving zimbra to a new disk

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, linux, zimbra

I've a Zimbra Release 6.0.8_GA_2661.DEBIAN5 DEBIAN5 FOSS edition installed on a Debian 5.0. My main disk was running low on space, so I've mounted an additional disk, shutted down zimbra, rsync-ed /opt/zimbra to the new disk, renamed /opt/zimbra to /opt/zimbra_old and mounted the new disk as /opt/zimbra

Trying to run zimbra with '/etc/init.d/zimbra start' complains about missing zmcontrol. So I've added /opt/zimbra/.bashrc with the following content:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/zimbra/bin
```

however, when I type "su - zimbra" the path doesn't get set and even with the following command it doesn't work.

```
$ sudo su - zimbra -c "source /opt/zimbra/.bashrc; echo $PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I've managed to start the server with:

```
sudo su zimbra -c "source /opt/zimbra/.bashrc ; /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcontrol start" 

Host xxxx.com
        Starting ldap...Done.
        Starting logger...Failed.
Starting logswatch...Unable to determine platform because /opt/zimbra/.platform does not exist.
failed.


        Starting mailbox...Done.
        Starting antispam...Done.
        Starting antivirus...Done.
        Starting snmp...Done.
        Starting spell...Done.
        Starting mta...Done.
        Starting stats...Done.
```

I can't find the .platform file even in the original directory.

Apart all these problems the server is now running but I would be happy to fix the problems, anyone has hints? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when you copied things over, you missed files with a leading period, most notably .bash_profile, .bashrc, .platform and .ldaprc.  The .saveconfig directory is also useful, though technically not required.

My [.bash_profile](http://pastebin.com/9VCDbVvZ) [.bashrc](http://pastebin.com/KktznhF5) and [.ldaprc](http://pastebin.com/sJFGjkNq) (pastebin links) under Ubuntu 8 x64 shows that the Zimbra path should also include half a dozen enteries under /opt/zimbra.  My guess is that your `/opt/zimbra/.platform` should be `DEBIAN5_64` or `DEBIAN5` (64/32bit) as mine is `UBUNTU8_64`.

Comment: I didn't delete the original directory and those files are still there, I missed them when rsyncing from zimbra_old/* - I copied the files in place, restarted zimbra and now it works, thank you!